# Is it possible to pass in a variable amount of parameters to a stored procedure in redshift?

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a stored procedure in AWS Redshift SQL and one of my parameters needs the possibility to have an integer list (will be using 'IN(0,100,200,...)' inside there WHERE clause). How would I write the input parameter in the header of the procedure so that this is possible (if at all?)

I've tried passing them in as a VARCHAR "integer list" type thing but wasn't sure then how to parse that back into ints.

Update: I found a way to parse the string and loop through it using the SPLIT_PART function and store all of those into a table. Then just use a SELECT * FROM table with the IN() call

Comment: Feel free to add an Answer to your own question if you think this will assist other readers.

Comment: The main question is how you are getting the integers into the Call. For example, is it a string or is it really a list of integers? Using Python would provide much more flexibility within the stored procedure itself — extracting integers from a comma-separated string would be trivial.

Comment: The way to get the integers in the call was done using a comma-separated string. I just wasn't entirely sure how to store them at first because I wasn't thinking with a database mindset. Once I realized that I could just create a temp table, the hard part was trying to find an easy function to use to count how many times to loop. I'll post my solution in an answer in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was as follows. I took in the integers that I was expecting as a comma-separated string. I then ran the following on it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_string_to_int(VARCHAR)
AS $$
DECLARE
    split_me ALIAS FOR $1;
    loop_var INT;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS int_list;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE int_list (
            integer_to_store INT
    );

    FOR loop_var IN 1..(REGEXP_COUNT(split_me,',') + 1) LOOP
            INSERT INTO int_list VALUES (CAST(SPLIT_PART(split_me,',',loop_var) AS INT));
    END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So I would call the procedure with something like:

```
CALL test_string_to_int('1,2,3');
```

and could do a select statement on it to see all the values stored into the table. Then in my queries the need this parameter I ran:

```
.........................
WHERE num_items IN(SELECT integer_to_store FROM int_list);
```